# Most Random Forest Features are the same

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I have a random forest with let's say 256 trees and say 2000 features. from data processing to actual prediction, it takes several hundred microseconds, I was wondering if there were any ways I could speed this up?

Is there anything extra I can do if I find that most of these 2000 features, bar a handful stay the same? ie suppose only 2 features varied, from my last prediction, would it make sense if I looked at a subset of this larger forest ie,
the 512 * 2 ^ 2 values the forest could give, if the other 1998 were the same.

Is there something out there that sounds similar to this? I guess in theory you might expect since each of those two features will have a 512 potential split points, you might have a continuous curve, however I imagine fitting a curve to these values would in itself be slow too...

Or is it possible to rephrase the problem to optimise for this scenario?

Comment: Do you want to speed up prediction time or training time? Do you really need it? Likely this is possible but would be more complicated and overall time for feature selection + training would be longer, plus there could be a drop in performance if the method is not perfect, so it might not be worth it.

Comment: Hey Tim, 
Speed up prediction time, is the main goal of this. I've already tried, just using the old values for the 1998 features, and I don't see much of a drop in performance. It's good enough... So given this I was thinking of trying to speed up the prediction time. I'm not sure of the most efficient way to do this. Maybe there's a way I can restructure the trees?

Comment: It seems like you omitted some important details of the problem: why and how would you use the “old values”? Are you predicting time-series?

Comment: If the features are constant ("stay the same"), then why are you including them in the model at all?